# How can I set a per-instance env variable for an elastic beanstalk docker container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Our elastic single-container beanstalk docker application runs as load balanced with multiple ec2 instances.

I want to pass the ec2 instance id of the machine it's running on as an environment variable to the docker container.
(I want to avoid doing AWS specific stuff inside the container).

I figure I need to put something in an .ebextension config file, where I do a curl to get the instance data and then set it into an environment variable that will be passed to the docker container.

Something like this (which doesn't work; it doesn't cause EB errors, but the env var is not available inside the container):

```
container_commands:
  set_instance_id:
    command: export EC2_INSTANCE_ID=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`
```

Ideally, I'd like to avoid hacking the EB run scripts, because they're undocumented and seem to change without notice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, at this moment, you **can not** do the thing that you want without cluttering your app with AWS specific stuff or modifying the EB script/deployment process.

**Options #1: Check for AWS Metadata from your app**

You can directly `curl` the AWS Metadata (http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id) directly from your Docker container.

[image: Run <code>curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id</code> inside Elastic Beanstalk Docker container]

From your app, if there is no environment name `EC2_INSTANCE_ID` (or anything you want), just call the AWS metadata service to get the instance id. FYI, 169.254.0.0/16 is a [link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address). You can also [detect your app is in AWS or not](https://serverfault.com/questions/462903/how-to-know-if-a-machine-is-an-ec2-instance).

**Options #2: Inject Dockerfile with environment variable**

Dockerfile can contain environment variable by using `ENV` keyword. We can inject a new environment variable using `ENV` into your Dockerfile. The environment variable injection your Dockerfile must be done after your app is extracted and before the Docker images is built.

Injecting Dockerfile can be done by **adding a pre-app-deployment hook**. Just create a new file inside the `appdeploy/pre` using `.ebextensions`:

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/02injectdockerfile.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    content: |
      . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/common.sh
      EB_CONFIG_APP_CURRENT=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_deploy_dir)
      cd $EB_CONFIG_APP_CURRENT
      echo "ENV EC2_INSTANCE_ID \"`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`\"" >> Dockerfile
```

Why must it be done in pre-appdeploy? Or can we just use `container_commands`?

The `container_commands` will be executed just before the app is deployed as the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-container_commands) said that. It looks like promising, but we can't use it. The `container_commands` will be executed after the Dockerfile is built (`docker build`). To use environment variable in Dockerfile, we need to inject the `ENV` before run `docker build`.

Take a look into [Elastic Beanstalk: Under the Hood](https://dev.bleacherreport.com/eb-under-the-hood-e7988736919f). Here is the file structure of appdeploy hook:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-62-137 ~]$ tree /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/
├── enact
│   ├── 00run.sh
│   └── 01flip.sh
├── post
│   └── 01_monitor_pids.sh
└── pre
    ├── 00clean_dir.sh
    ├── 01unzip.sh
    ├── 02docker_db_check.sh
    └── 03build.sh
```

The app file is extracted in `pre/01unzip.sh` and `docker build` is executed in `pre/03build.sh`. So, we need add a new script to inject the `ENV` with the script file name order is after `01unzip.sh` and before `03build.sh`. As you said, this is undocumented and might be changed. But, I thought, it should not be changed if you use same Elastic Beanstalk platform version. You need to verify this "hack" can be run in the next platform version before you upgrade the production environment.

Actually, there any some other options to set instance id as environment variable. Such as: modifying the `docker run` line in `enact/00run.sh`. I also don't prefer to modify the EB script.

Comment: Hi @Shorn, is this enough for your app or there are some specific requirement?

Comment: As stated in the question, I want to avoid doing AWS specific things from within the container.  It runs in other contexts besides AWS. I want to push the identifier (and other instance specific things later) in as a dependency/configuration item, rather than have an AWS dependency inside the container.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I didn't clear with "AWS specific stuff inside container". If you want exactly like that (without modify your app or EB deployment process), I thought, there are no answers for your question.

Comment: I'm going to use your Option #2.  Yes, it may stop working on a future solution stack updgrade, but not much I can do about that.  Copy/pasted straight from your snippet and it seems to work fine - thanks.